# How to fetch values from database and function?

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

I have two source of data where i want to get from. One source is from database, and another one is value that is hardcoded from a function. I am not sure how can I fetch data from both. My controller is as following:

```
if (!permission) {
  return res.status(403).end();
}

const configs = await Config.query();

newConfig.getConfig();
```

// function get.Config() created to fetch value inside this function

Meanwhile, my function is as following:

```
const newConfig = {
  minDeposit: 20,
  minWithdrawal: 20,
  maxDeposit: 50000,
};

function getConfig() {
  return newConfig;
}

export default {
  getConfig,
};
```

My objective is to get data from database, which is Config.query() and get all values from get.Config() function.

note that database have name, and value column and when this query: const configs = await Config.query(); get executed, it shall return data in json format

Comment: What is the issue over here?

Comment: i am not sure how to get values from both query and hardcoded value in function @Prerak Sola